# Issue setting domain memory

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, air

I'm testing decoding base-64 data, reading it efficiently through [`ApplicationDomain#domainMemory`](https://airsdk.dev/reference/actionscript/3.0/flash/system/ApplicationDomain.html#domainMemory), inside a background worker:

```
override public function decode(): Array {
    ...
    ApplicationDomain.currentDomain.domainMemory = task.input;
    ...
}
```

I've noticed that I'm receiving an "End of file" error exactly from that assignment to `domainMemory` with a `task.input` of 16 bytes that has been received from the main worker.

> Error #1504: End of file.

I've tested my similiar `encode()` function and it produces no such error.

### MCVE

Run https://github.com/agera-air/org.agera.crypto by running the script `run/test` with the following requirements:

- Node.js
- `asconfigc`

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import org.agera.crypto.*;
    import org.agera.util.*;

    public class Main extends Sprite {
        public function Main() {
            encrypt("Some string", EncryptionFormat.BASE_64)
                .then(function(data: String): void {
                    assertEquals(data, "U29tZSBzdHJpbmc=");
                    trace("Base-64 encryption .. OK");
                })
                .otherwise(function(error: Error): void {
                    trace("Base-64 encryption .. ERROR");
                });
            decrypt("U29tZSBzdHJpbmc=", EncryptionFormat.BASE_64)
                .then(function(data: String): void {
                    assertEquals(data, "Some string");
                    trace("Base-64 decryption .. OK");
                })
                .otherwise(function(error: Error): void {
                    trace(error.message);
                    trace("Base-64 decryption .. ERROR");
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide MCVE (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example), the current provided code  does not at all clarify the problem.

Comment: Also, you might want to check this: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/ApplicationDomain.html#MIN_DOMAIN_MEMORY_LENGTH

Comment: @Organis This made me realize that I was setting `domainMemory` to the wrong `ByteArray`!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was a minor typo in my code when copying algorithm codes from the `by.blooddy.crypto` cryptography library:

In `packages/org.agera.crypto.worker/src/org/agera/crypto/worker/formats/Base64.as`, changed from

```
override public function decode(): Array {
    ...
    if (memory.length < ApplicationDomain.MIN_DOMAIN_MEMORY_LENGTH) {
        memory.length = ApplicationDomain.MIN_DOMAIN_MEMORY_LENGTH;
    }

    ApplicationDomain.currentDomain.domainMemory = task.input;
    ...
}
```

to...

```
override public function decode(): Array {
    ...
    if (memory.length < ApplicationDomain.MIN_DOMAIN_MEMORY_LENGTH) {
        memory.length = ApplicationDomain.MIN_DOMAIN_MEMORY_LENGTH;
    }

    ApplicationDomain.currentDomain.domainMemory = memory;
    ...
}
```